# Connecting to Access from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I have an ASP.NET application (written with VB.NET) that needs to connect to an Access 2007 DB to execute some select statements. I'm having trouble connecting to my Access DB.

Here is the code I'm tryng...

```
Dim MDBConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\resus.accdb;Persist Security Info=false"
Dim cnn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(MDBConnectionString)
cnn.Open()
```

The error I get is the following...

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Unspecified error
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
at Resuscitation.ReportGenerator.Generate(Page ThisPage, Boolean blnPerformSelfTest)
```

I also tried putting my accdb file in the App_Data folder and then used the following connection string...

```
Dim MDBConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|resus.accdb;"
```

That gave me the same error.

I tried the code in a Windows Forms Application and it worked fine.

What am I missing here to get this to work in my ASP.NET application?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it's a permission issue to the folder containing the mdb file

Comment: @ilanS agreed, it is very unlikely that the identity running the site has access to the root of c:\

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm getting this error while running my ASP.NET application in Visual Studio. I put my accbd file in the root folder only because it wasn't working when I had the file in the App_Data folder.

Comment: Tweak both your WinForms app and your ASP.NET app to show you the results of `String.Format("{0}-bit", IntPtr.Size * 8)`. Do they show you the same value?

Comment: Both show me 32-bit.